# Using PHP variable and passing Data to window.open using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript function

This code opens page in a new window

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
        var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
        var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
    } 
</script>
```

Now I have this code to get the Id from a MySQL Database which looks like this :

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ('Cannot connect: '.mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM new_reservation";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Bad Query: '.mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$ResID = $row['id'];

}
?>
```

Now I want to use this same ID in the javascript function I created like so

```
onclick=\"OpenPopupCenter('signout_visitor.php?id=', 'TEST!?', 1200, 600);\"
```

I am not quite sure how to use this. Quite a bit new to using variables in popup windows for javascript hence i would be needing some form of clarification here.

**Edit**

I am using it in a Table like this

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect, Reason: '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "select * from new_reservation ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Failed Query , Reason : '.mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $showData = "<TR valign=top>
<TD width=106 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1><BR></font></div>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1>&nbsp;&nbsp; {$row['visit_date']}</font></div>
</div>
</TD>
<TD width=134 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1><BR></font></div>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1>&nbsp; {$row['login_time']}</font></div>
</div>
</TD>
<TD width=148 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div><font face=Verdana size=1><BR></font></div>
<div><font face=Verdana size=1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {$row['fullname']}</font></div>
</div>
</TD>
<TD width=160 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1><BR></font></div>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana size=1>&nbsp;&nbsp; {$row['whom_tosee']}</font></div>
</div>
</TD>
<TD width=138 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div align=center><font face=Verdana><input type=image src=images/show_detailsbtn.png width=124 height=26 onclick=\"OpenPopupCenter('shownewvisitdetails.php?id=$ResID', 'TEST!?', 1200, 600);\" ></font></div>
</div>
</TD>
<TD width=163 height=26><div class=wpmd>
<div><BR></div>
<div>&nbsp;<font face=Verdana size=2>
    <input type=image src=images/signout_visitor.png width=121 height=27 onclick=\"OpenPopupCenter('signout_visitor.php?id=$ResID', 'TEST!?', 1200, 600);\"></font></div>
</div>
</TD>
</TR>
";
    echo $showData;

}
?>
```

Comment: @Darksymphony its on a table . Please See edits.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need “clarification” on here in the first place. How to get your PHP variable’s content to be output after the `?id=` part in your function call? Well either via string concatenation or echo, depends on how that function call is currently output. And if(?) the other part of the question is how to access query string parameters using Javascript - please do a bit of proper research on that, that is everything but a new topic.

Comment: i use the first PHP to get the row ID now after i get the Row ID then i use the first javascript function in my code to open the URL and transfer the RowID variable so that when a button is clicked, it automatically opens in a new window with something like this on the url http://localhost/showdetails.php?id=2

Comment: So all you have to do for that part is append the ID to the URL you are outputting as the function parameter …

Comment: @04FS, yes. I have edited the code and showed what i did. Please See the second PHP

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is a little bit confusing to me. Can you be clear about what you are trying to achieve?

1) Do you need the URL params (i mean id) from URL you can use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

in PHP and

```
window.location
```

in JS.

2) if you want to pass the result data to the newly opened window try this

```
let windowNew = window.open('https://www.yahiya.com');

windowNew.array= $dataArray;
```

and in your new window use

```
windowNew.array;
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a variable safely

Comment: i use the first PHP to get the row ID now after i get the Row ID then i use the first javascript function in my code to open the URL and transfer the RowID variable so that when a button is clicked, it automatically opens in a new window with something like this on the url localhost/showdetails.php?id=2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ID from PHP in your javascript, just after php code simply use this:

```
onclick=\"OpenPopupCenter('signout_visitor.php?id=<?php echo $ResID;?>', 'TEST!?', 1200, 600);\"
```